# ng-if didn't change on ng-click button

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, boolean

i want to change the word from me to your using ng-if in angular JS. so i used this code :

```
 <span class="label-information-text" ng-if="changeValue" >me </span>
                <span class="label-information-text" ng-if="!changeValue"> your</span>
                <span class="label-edit-text pointer" ng-click="change()">CHANGE </span>
```

and i used this js:

```
 self.changeValue = true;
        $scope.change = function () {
          if(self.changeValue === false){

            self.changeValue = true;
          console.log('true');
          }
          else{
            self.changeValue = false;
            console.log('false');
          }

        }
```

Comment: Did you get that console.log() values in console?

Comment: is your controller written as `ng-controller="myCtrl"` or `ng-controller="myCtrl as vm"`? You are using `self`, which is I'm assuming is the controller itself, i.e. `var self = this;`. Because of that you need _controllerAs_ syntax everywhere. Change `$scope.change` to `self.change` and in HTML use `vm.change()`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is true but there is a little change as below.

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
var self = this;

 self.changeValue = true;
        self.change = function () {
          if(self.changeValue === false){

            self.changeValue = true;
          console.log('true');
          }
          else{
            self.changeValue = false;
            console.log('false');
          }

        }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as $ctrl">

 <span class="label-information-text" ng-if="$ctrl.changeValue" >me </span>
                <span class="label-information-text" ng-if="!$ctrl.changeValue"> your</span>
                </br>
                <span class="label-edit-text pointer" ng-click="$ctrl.change()">CHANGE </span>
                
              
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`ngShow`** directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.When the **`ngShow`** expression evaluates to a falsy value then the .ng-hide CSS class is added to the class attribute on the element causing it to become hidden. When truthy, the .ng-hide CSS class is removed from the element causing the element not to appear hidden.

**`ngIf`** differs from **`ngShow`** and **`ngHide`** in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than
    changing its visibility via the display css property.

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed
>   and a new scope is created when the element is restored.

You should use **`ng-show`**,

To be success.

Answer (score -1):

Here is working code:

```
    <button class="btn" ng-click="change()">CHANGE </button>
      <span class="label-information-text" ng-if="changeValue" ><b>ME</b> </span>
    <span class="label-information-text" ng-if="!changeValue"> <b>YOUR</b></span>
```

JS

```
$scope.changeValue = true;
        $scope.change = function () {
          if($scope.changeValue === false){

            $scope.changeValue = true;
          console.log('true');
          }
          else{
            $scope.changeValue = false;
            console.log('false');
          }

        }
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ndDbpsPiY20BbmSgHqCW?p=preview